# In node.js, is it possible to create a timeout (e.g. setTimeout) that does *not* block the process from completing

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to be able to detect whether the current script is hanging. To do that I want to do something like this:

```
setWeakTimeout(function() {
  console.log("Your script is hanging!")
}, 5000)
```

Normal `setTimeout` won't work because the process will *always* wait for that timeout callback to be called. I need something that is cancelled automatically when the script has no more continuations to process. Is this possible?

Comment: Do what now? Why would the script be hanging, and shouldn't you use your efforts on fixing that instead.

Comment: My unit testing suite sometimes hangs because... test driven development? We need some red text to ensure we don't commit otherwise-passing tests that hang.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`unref`](http://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_unref):

```
function setWeakTimeout() {
    var ret = setTimeout.apply(this, arguments);
    ret.unref()
    return ret;
}

setWeakTimeout(function() {
  console.log("Your script is hanging!")
}, 5000)
```

Calling `unref` makes Node not wait for this timeout to complete before exiting. The code above will exit right away. If you comment out the call to `unref`, it will hang for 5 seconds.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand this correctly you just need to define a global:

```
var t = setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("Your script is hanging!");
}, 5000);
```

and once the script finishes all it has to do fire

```
clearTimeout(t);
```

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood. How do you know when the script finishes? If the script finishes, then there is no more code to run, ie no code that could possibly call clearTimeout

Comment: @BT Well, you've written the script so you should know what is the last expected line to be called. Just add `clearTimeout` after it.

Comment: The whole point is I don't know what the last line is - its in a buggy callback or something. Louis gave the answer

Answer (score -1):

You could put the clearTimeout (and other things like closing db connections) in:

```
process.on('exit', function () {
    clearTimeout (t);        // from freakish's answer

    // db.end ();
    console.log( "App ending..." );
});
```

Always nice to have a cleanup.

Comment: Had you tried this, you'll discover this will never ever work. By default, process.on('exit') will never fire while a setTimeout call is active - therefore the timeout will always fire. Also, had you read my question, you would have learned this already.